# Как одновременно запустить Flask и Pyrogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyrogram

Как одновременно запустить Flask и Pyrogram?
Хочу установить слушатель событий на Flask и на Pyrogram в одной программе, как это реализовать?

Comment: на пример использовать ассинхронку или потоки.

Comment: а можно чуть подробнее, как это организовать лучше? Не шарю за потоки

Comment: Все подробности хорощо описаны в документаций модуля threading. за кодом по ссылке https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=threading